# C++: class that stores object with unknown type as member variable

Tags: c++, templates

I'm C++ beginner and trying to define class that uses object with unknown type. This class should take this object as argument and then store it as member variable.

I known that I need use templates for this kind of problem. I also managed to do template function that works but I'm having problems with the class. Hopefully the code example will clarify my problem.

Just define few base classes for testing purposes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    string m_s;

    Base(string s)
    {
        m_s = s;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hello " + m_s << endl;
    }
};

class Base2
{
public:
    string m_s;

    Base2(string s)
    {
        m_s = s;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hey " + m_s << endl;
    }
};
```

Define Derived class that should take object as argument and store it as member variable:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived
{
public:
    T m_c;

    Derived(T c)
    {
        T m_c = c;
    }

    void print()
    {
        m_c.print();
    }
};
```

Testing:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto b1 = Base("b1");
    auto b2 = Base2("b2");

    // This will give compile error:
    // no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’ 
    auto d1 = Derived<Base>(b1);
    auto d2 = Derived<Base2>(b2);
    d1.print();
    d2.print();
}
```

On the other hand, if I just define function template, it works without problems.

```
template <typename T>
void print(T c)
{
    c.print();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto b1 = Base("b1");
    auto b2 = Base2("b2");

    // This works!
    print(b1);
    print(b2);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Derived(T c) : m_c(c) {}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class member without a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328150/class-member-without-a-default-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes haven`t default constructors, in this case try the following code:

```
 Derived(T c) : m_c(c)
{

}
```

Or you can add Base2() {} and Base() {}  to the appropriate classes. 
But in this case all members of these classes will call the default constructors and you will print default values.

[Also I`d like to advise you to read the rule of three.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))
This will allow you to better understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link!